# JavaScript not putting Username in url

Tags: javascript

Go to http://oxidepkz.net63.net/vote.php
that is what the full php file looks like, so whats wrong is i have a username that suppose to go into a mysql database. the user name is the text box, i think all i need is the username in the urls from the button click, not the actual php page.
Here is a snippet of the Script code:

```
<script>
function next() {
if(document.vote.username.value.length == 0) {
    alert("The username field cannot be left empty.");
} else if(document.vote.username.value.length > 30) {
    alert("You've reached the maximum amount of characters.");
} else {
    document.vote.username.disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('button').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('nextbutton').style.display = "none";
}
}
 function changeAction(url) {
if(url.indexOf("rspscoding.org") != -1) {
    var username = document.vote.username.value;
    document.vote.action = ""+url+"&username="+username+"";
} else {
    document.vote.action = url;
}
  }
 </script>
 <title>Vote</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<center><br>
<br><br>
<div class="vote"><br><br>
<form name="vote" class="short style" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input name="username" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30"          placeholder="Username"><button id="nextbutton" type="button"     onClick="next();">Next</button>
    <div style="display: none;" id="button" class="button"><button type="submit" onClick="changeAction('http://www.rune-server.org/toplist.php?do=vote&sid=8289&name=');")>Rune-Server</button><button type="submit" onClick="changeAction('http://www.runelocus.com/toplist/index.php?action=vote&id=30838&id2=');")>RuneLocus</button></div>
</form><br>
```

Comment: "Go to http://oxidepkz.net63.net/vote.php " No.

Comment: please do not comment on something that is not helpful thanks, its a link to see the full vote page, not to comment "No."

Comment: Please don't TELL people to visit your random/sketchy site to access the code for YOUR problem. If it's relevant, post it here.

Comment: i didnt say you had too?? all im asking is how to get the button click to have the username in the url, from the input of the text box???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what I see, when your code does the changeAction function, it checks for rspscoding.org in the URL.  However, the URLs you are passing in with both of the buttons has nowhere in it a reference to rspscoding.org.  Therefore, the else statement is firing, not passing in the username, causing your problem.

Try eliminating the if statement or changing the URL location checker to a different URL.  If that doesn't work, I don't know what will.  Good luck!

Comment: so just take the whole if statement out ?

Comment: I would think so, unless you're using the if statement for a special reason.  If so, then change rspscoding.org to a different URL that's actually in the URLs passed into the function.  Otherwise, yes, just remove the whole if statement and just have the code inside the if block.

Comment: you mean the url the page is on?? or the url the click button directs them to?

Comment: I think I would just remove the if statement all together and just have the code inside the if block.

Comment: you mean the url the page is on?? or the url the click button directs them to?